# Threading in MVP pattern

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am currently writing a program that takes input from the user and makes a http get request to a server.The request will send back data in an object that I return to the presenter inside a object I am having a problem understanding where threading would fit in this particular design pattern. Let's say my presenter has X number of methods:

```
public void method1()
{
  //Make call to service project to execute http request
  someobject = serviceRequest.MakeRequest();
}

public void method2()
{
  //Make call to service project to execute http request
  someobject = serviceRequest.MakeAnotherRequest();
}

public void method3()
{
  someobject = serviceRequest.Make3rdRequest();
}
```

How can I launch these methods in a separate thread? Any help is appreciated. BTW I'm using .net 3.5. I have access to VS2010 if somebody's solution calls for it. Thanks.

Comment: You may be better off using the Async/Await pattern in your design.  This requires 4.5 framework.  You should indicate which version of the .Net framework you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Task`:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(new Task(() => serviceRequest.MakeRequest()));
tasks.Add(new Task(() => serviceRequest.MakeAnotherRequest()));
tasks.Add(new Task(() => serviceRequest.Make3rdRequest()));
//...
//Somewhere in your code
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Each task here is added to the threadpool and you can use `WhenAll` or a series of other methods to control and access the tasks and their return values.

Comment: Sorry I don't have .net 4.5